# iOS 10 WEBRTC HTML5 video ignores CSS z-index

Tags: javascript, html5-video, ionic2, webrtc, mobile-safari

I will like to correct an issue where a large HTML5 video tag is covering all other absolutely positioned elements on the same page which are not video elements. I have seen some posts on issues such as these but for the most part, they're trying to use some plugin thats doing some blocking somewhere.

I am testing WRTC on iOS and i am trying to place a div with some actionable parts over a video element which fills the screen.

I have two video elements (large and small) which both stack properly with respect to themselves but all other elements are hidden once the large video frame loads its stream. Setting the z-index to -1 causes the video to disappear completely and it just shows a black div.

Like I said...this is happening on an iPhone 5 running iOS 10.

**CSS**

```
.video-container {
        &-large {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            object-fit: cover;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
            position: absolute;
            left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
            z-index: 0;
        }
}
```

[image]